# How add administrator to team in Azure DevOps using SDK or Web Api?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-sdk-.net

I try to create a team using SDK. And it creates it without any members and administrators:

```
WebApiTeam team = new WebApiTeam
        {
            Name = "New Team",
            ProjectId = project.Id
        };
```

then call

```
public virtual Task<WebApiTeam> CreateTeamAsync(WebApiTeam team, string projectId, object userState = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

And as a result, I have a team with the name "New Team" without any members and admins.
Then i add members into team:

```
public Task<bool> AddMemberToGroupAsync(IdentityDescriptor containerId, Guid memberId, object userState = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
containerId = myNewTeam.id;
memberId=(user || group).id;
```

but how to add admins into team idk.
I found that when we do this manually it call

```
http://{baseUrl}/tfs/{project}/{teamId}/_api/_identity/AddTeamAdmins?__v=5
```

I try to call this using postman but I can't authorize. Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is my answer helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using tfs, you need to note that the Azure DevOps Command Line Interface (CLI) is available for **Azure DevOps Server 2020** and Azure DevOps Services. This is stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops-2020).

> I try to call this using postman but I can't authorize

You need to use PAT with full scopes for certification.

[image]

Here is my test:

[image]

Comment: I'm getting an error, `The required anti-forgery cookie &quot;__RequestVerificationToken&quot; is not present. Ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.` Sounds like this request is maybe not allowed as a REST API call anymore? Using Azure DevOps Services.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by assigning the users the correct permissions on the team's security namespace. Here's an example that adds two users as admins to a new team.

```
$myOrg = "https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/"
$newTeam = "My New Team"
$newAdmin = "user1@me.com"
$myProject = "My Project"

az login

$team = az devops team create --name $newTeam --org $myOrg --project $myProject | ConvertFrom-Json

$user = az devops user show --user $newAdmin  --organization $myOrg | ConvertFrom-Json
az devops security group membership add --group-id $team.identity.subjectDescriptor --member-id $user.user.descriptor --org $myOrg
az devops security permission update --id "5a27515b-ccd7-42c9-84f1-54c998f03866" --subject $user.user.principalName --token "$($team.projectId)\$($team.id)" --allow-bit 31  --org $myOrg
```